# Retrieve Data from a dictionary website

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently studying on TOEFL. What I want to do is writing words to excel and retrieve their meanings in Turkish from a website. Here is what I did so far.

```
Sub tureng()

Dim ieObj

Set ieObj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim kelime As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sayfa1")
For i = 1 To sht.Range("A10000").End(3).Row
    kelime = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value

  With ieObj
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://tureng.com/tr/turkce-ingilizce/" & kelime
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
      DoEvents
    Loop
  End With
Next

End Sub
```

With these codes, I can open the required website but I don't know how to get the meanings. I only want to get first two or three words. Meanings will be in the same row with the main word but they can be in the separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer, here is some improved code which has simple error handling and is a lot more easily adapted to work with a given number of words (in your example 3). Note this is untested but based on the code which you say is working (and which you have since deleted)...

```
Sub tureng()

    Dim ieObj As Object

    Set ieObj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim allRowOfData As Object
    Dim kelime As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    ' If you are using the values immediately in your sheet, you don't need to store them

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sayfa1")

    Dim i as Integer
    Dim j as Integer

    For i = 1 To sht.Range("A10000").End(3).Row

        kelime = sht.Cells(i, 1).Value

        With ieObj
            .Visible = False
            .Navigate "http://tureng.com/tr/turkce-ingilizce/" & kelime
            Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
            Loop
            Set allRowOfData = ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("tr ts")

            ' Very simple error handling code, simply try 3 times regardless of failure
            On Error Resume Next
            For j = 1 to 3 ' Loop to get up to 3 values

                sht.Cells(i, j+1).Value = allRowOfData(j).innertext

            Next j
            On Error GoTo 0

        End With

    Next I

    ieObj.Quit

End Sub
```